# Using glMatrixMode() in succession?

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-compat

How would one go about using two different matrix modes in succession? I.e, say I want to do some operations using `glOrtho()` to the projection matrix. So I call `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)`, and then perform the operations. From my understanding, using `glPushMatrix()` will apply these changes to the projection matrix. Now I want to apply some changes to the modelview matrix. I am confused on how to do this properly. Do I pop the matrix then call `glMatrixMode` or simply continue with `glMatrixMode`?

Comment: [`glPushMatrix()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) doesn't apply any changes. Any matrix operation changes the current matrix in the current mode. But there is a stack of matrices for each of the matrix modes. `glPushMatrix` pushes the current matrix to the stack and `glPopMatrix` pops it. Use the mode `GL_PROJECTION` for the projection matrix and the `GL_MODELVIEW` for the view and model matrix. Note, each vertex is first transformed by the modelview and after that by the projection matrix. The order matters.

Comment: Don't fret with the [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) matrix stack. This is deprecated since decades. If you don't know it yet, then there is no need to look into it any more. Read about [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) and [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification). A good tutorial is [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` are to store/restore currently selected matrix. Its used for example for sub meshes (like robotic arm) where you need to return to the state of the root submesh ...

What you describe is what `glMatrixMode` is for. So your code should look like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
// here your stuff for setting projection
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
// here your stuff for setting modelview
```

you should call `glMatrixMode` before each block of code that is manipulating matrix. Do not expect current matrix is set to stuff you set it to last. That leads to confusion later on ... for example many draw algos change modelview and or texture matrices on the run and in your code you can have something like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
// here your stuff for setting modelview
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
// here your stuff for setting projection

object1.draw();

// and here the current matrix could be changed from the object1.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    glPushMatrix(); glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(a, b, c,d,  e,f);// 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     glPushMatrix(); glLoadIdentity();


//----------
//----------

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float mat_proj[16];
float mat_model[16];    

glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,mat_proj );
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX ,mat_model);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(a,b,c,d,e,f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);glLoadIdentity(); 
//---------
//---------
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);   glLoadMatrixf(mat_proj);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    glLoadMatrixf(mat_model);
```